# How to minimize repetition in tox file

Tags: python, testing, tox, test-environments

**Goal:** Successfully execute specific tox commands, and have it run for "just" that specific matched command.

Example: `tox -e py35-integration`

`tox` should run only for py35-integration and *not* including the *default* or standalone `py35` definition.

I have tried two different approaches, which as far as I understand are the two ways to go about trying to do what I'm trying to do.

- note the `flake8` command is to easily isolate between different commands and indicate to me what is running. It is not an indication of the command I'm really trying to run.

Furthermore, ini files are only showing relevant parts.

## First approach

```
[tox]
envlist = {py27,py35}, {py27,py35}-integration

[testenv]
commands =
    py27: python -m testtools.run discover
    py35: python -m testtools.run discover
    py27-integration: flake8 {posargs}
    py35-integration: flake8 {posargs}
```

With this approach, the understanding here is that I want to have `tox -e py27-integration` run without also running what is defined for the `py27` command. This is not what is happening. Instead, it will run both `py27` and `py27-integration`.

## Second approach

```
[tox]
envlist = {py27,py35}, {py27,py35}-integration

[testenv]
commands =
    python -m testtools.run discover

[testenv:integration]
commands = 
    flake8 {posargs}
```

Now, here I am explicitly isolating for a "sub" environment with its own command to run for "integration".

However, unfortunately, I'm met with the exact same behaviour of all matched patterns of "py27" being executed.

I'm trying to avoid repeating testenv structures as: `[testenv:py27-integration]` and `[testenv:py35-integration]`, which contain the exact same definitions (goal is to minimize repetition).

I would love to know if there is a way I can achieve what I am trying to do.

I do not want to venture down doing something like `p27-integration` as an alternative naming scheme, since our CI pipelines have templates expecting certain name structures, and these names are also idiomatic to tox, in that `py27` for example is understood to install a 2.7 virtual environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updated*

```
[tox]
minversion = 3.15
envlist = {py27,py35}, {py27,py35}-integration

[testenv]
commands =
    python -m testtools.run discover

[testenv:py{27,35}-integration]
commands = 
    flake8 {posargs}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, this does seem to give me the separation of commands I'm looking for, which is great. Unfortunately, it still doesn't solve the repetition problem where I still have to create those sub environments. If I were able to just somehow have one [integration] that would be *the* solution. This a step in the right direction though. Thank you.

Comment: @idjaw See the updated answer: `tox` 3.15+ allows even better condensing.

Comment: Thanks for the ping. That's really clean and still relevant to some older projects that can use this update. :)